Delineating TOC Subsection Entries Horizontally (Instead of Vertically)
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=red,
    filecolor=red,
    linkcolor=red,
    urlcolor=red
}

\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vspace*{3pt}} 
\renewcommand\cftsubsecafterpnum{\vskip 5pt}  


\cftpagenumbersoff{section}
\cftpagenumbersoff{subsection}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}

\section*{JANUARY}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{JANUARY}

\subsection*{January 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 1}

\subsection*{January 2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 2}

\subsection*{January 3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 3}

\subsection*{January 4}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 4}

\subsection*{January 5}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 5}

\subsection*{January 6}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 6}

\subsection*{January 7}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 7}

\subsection*{January 8}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 8}

\subsection*{January 9}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 9}

\subsection*{January 10}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 10}

\subsection*{January 11}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 11}

\subsection*{January 12}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Jan 12}


\newpage
\tableofcontents
\end{document}

which produces


QUESTION: How may I delineate the TOC subsection entries horizontally (instead of vertically)? I would like for these particular entries not to take up too much vertical space in the TOC.
Thank you.

Start here: How do I get multiple ToC entries in the same line?

This answer replaces the \addcontentsline command as defined by hyperref with \addcontentslinex to align subsections entries horizontally in the table of contents.
\addcontentslinex is initially defined as \addcontentsline and then patched to obtain the desired behavior. Note that hyperlinks are preserved.

\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vspace*{8pt}} %optional <<<
\renewcommand{\cftbeforesecskip}{\baselineskip} %optional <<<
\renewcommand{\cftsecindent}{0pt} %optional <<<
    
\cftpagenumbersoff{section}
\cftpagenumbersoff{subsection}

\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref} % Here !!! (last package) <<<<<<<<<<<
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=red,
    filecolor=red,
    linkcolor=red,
    urlcolor=red
}

%***************************************** added after hyperref <<<<
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\let\addcontentslinex\addcontentsline % new command \addcontentslinex

\xpatchcmd{\addcontentslinex} % patch addcontentslinex
{\addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{\thepage}{\@currentHref}\protected@file@percent}}
{\addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{}{\mbox{#3}\hspace{1.5ex}}{}{\@currentHref}\protected@file@percent}}
{}{}
\makeatother
%*****************************************


\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{plain}       
        
    \section*{JANUARY}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{JANUARY}
    
    \subsection*{January 1}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Jan 1}
    
    \subsection*{January 2}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Jan 2}
    
    \subsection*{January 3}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Jan 3}
    
    \subsection*{January 4}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Jan 4}
    
    \subsection*{January 5}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Jan 5}
    
    \subsection*{January 6}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Jan 6}
    
    \subsection*{January 7}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Jan 7}
    
    \subsection*{January 8}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Jan 8}
    
    \subsection*{January 9}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Jan 9}
    
    \subsection*{January 10}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Jan 10}
    
    \subsection*{January 11}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Jan 11}
    
    \subsection*{January 12}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Jan 12}
    
        \subsection*{January 13}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Jan 13}
    
    \subsection*{January 14}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Jan 14}
    
    \clearpage
    
     \section*{FEBRUARY}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{FEBRUARY}
    
    \subsection*{February 1}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Feb 1}
    
    \subsection*{February 2}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Feb 2}
    
    \subsection*{February 3}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Feb 3}
    
    \subsection*{February 4}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Feb 4}
    
    \subsection*{February 5}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Feb 5}
    
    \subsection*{February 6}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Feb 6}
    
    \subsection*{February 7}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Feb 7}
    
    \subsection*{February 8}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Feb 8}
    
    \subsection*{February 9}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Feb 9}
    
    \subsection*{February 10}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Feb 10}
    
    \subsection*{February 11}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Feb 11}
    
    \subsection*{February 12}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Feb 12}
    
    \subsection*{February 13}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Feb 13}
    
    \subsection*{February 14}
    \addcontentslinex{toc}{subsection}{Feb 14}
    
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
\end{document}


Thank you for posting this answer.
